# Enable 4 GB RAM usage on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, memory, 32-bit, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5 GB of my more than 4 GB of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086)

I have 4 GB of RAM which I understand is the maximum for Windows 7 32 bit. My system recognizes the 4 GB and is able to use 2.9 GB. Of course, I'm interested in using all 4 GB. I have tried booting with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) on, but I still get only 2.9 GB usable. How is this? Is the rest of the RAM actually mapped, and the system just doesn't realize this, or do I have to do something else to get maximum performance for my 4 GB of RAM?

Comment: I know that question refers to XP not Windows 7, but the key thing is that you're running a 32 bit OS.

Comment: Not really though, because "not possible" is not really the answer I'm looking for. I Know it requires a hacky solution, but that's why I am asking. The adresses are being used right now, but I want to force the adresses to my RAM so I can use them fully. So what I am actually looking for is what I am asking for; WHY - when I am using the PAE - Physical address extension, is it not working?

Comment: MS refused to allow 32-bit desktop windows to use more than 4GB of address space. Suppposedly due to buggy drivers. If you want to use more than 4GB of address space on 32-bit windows you can either upgrade to a server edition or hack the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Read the page *[3GB Switch in Windows boot.ini](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/3GB+switch+Windows+boot.ini+3+GB)*.

Comment: The 3GB switch has nothing whatsoever to do with this. That switch has to do with virtual addresses, not physical.