# Limit to the RAM on Windows Vista 32-bit

Tags: windows-vista, memory

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Enable 4gb ram usage on win 7 32-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/173745/enable-4gb-ram-usage-on-win-7-32-bit)
>   [Windows XP and RAM 3.5GB+](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb)

Is there a limit to the RAM on Windows Vista 32-bit. For example, Can I use 8 GB of RAM  on Windows Vista 32-bit.

Comment: @Sathy, that'll create a chain of dupes, so I'm suggesting it as a dupe of the base question instead: [Windows XP and RAM 3.5GB+](http://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb).

Comment: @DMA: there are a whole bunch of similar questions :) http://superuser.com/questions/50138/4-gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2-97gb-usable-what-gives-closed / http://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb
 / http://superuser.com/questions/7964/where-did-the-other-8-gb-of-ram-go / http://superuser.com/questions/17827/using-3-gb-ram-in-vista-windows732-bit
 / http://superuser.com/questions/54056/why-is-usable-ram-less-than-total-ram
 / http://superuser.com/questions/27006/how-to-check-ram-size-without-looking-at-motherboard / http://superuser.com/questions/76114

Comment: @Sathya I know, but we may as well try and link the new ones to a common base as much as is possible.

Comment: @DMA573 Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

You mean 8GB :-)
And no it will not be shown after 4GB until you switch to a 64bits OS ...

Answer (score 0):

When you want to install more then 3.5 GB, in a 32 bit version it won't be used. Windows 32 will say to you that there is for example (system properties) 4 GB installed, but only 3.5 will be really used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, 2, No, see this explanation

http://www.asisupport.com/ts_4GB_memory_info.htm