# How to Total 4 GB RAM usable in windows Xp?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5GB of my 4GB+ of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5gb-of-my-4gb-of-ram)

I have a a Lenovo G560 Laptop ...i have 4 GB ram in laptop but in windows XP its shows 2.93 GB usable ..

But i want it uses total 4 GB RAM ...

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to a 64-bit OS so that all of the memory can be addressed.

Comment: PAE does exist...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can upgrade to [Windows XP Professional x64 Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_Professional_x64_Edition), but there are a bunch of little limitations and compatibility issues you might have with it.

Since you're going to have to buy a new Windows License anyway, you might as well upgrade to Vista or Windows 7.  Windows XP almost 10 years old, and nearing the end of its life.

According to a couple websites selling the Lenovo G560, it ships with Windows 7 64-bit these days, so there should be no compatibility problems.

Comment: Skip Vista and get the Windows 7 license.