# Why is my 32-bit XP professional showing 4GB Ram as 3 GB?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5GB of my 4GB+ of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5gb-of-my-4gb-of-ram)

I have a 32-bit system that was previously having 2 GB RAM(DDR2 800 MHZ), i added one more 2 GB RAM(DDR2 800 MHZ), bu it is showing the total ram size in My Computer properties as 3 GB only.

can any body please tell me what might be the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

32 bit systems can only address 4GB of memory. This upper limit on addressable space is shared by all the devices that need to map memory, RAM, Graphics cards, other hardware adapters... That means that, depending on your hardware configuration, part of your 4 GB RAM cannot be addressed by the system.