# not getting whole of my computer's ram

Tags: 64-bit, memory, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5GB of my 4GB+ of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5gb-of-my-4gb-of-ram)

i have 8 GB of ram in my desktop but it shows "3.47gb is usable" how to get whole usage of the ram. please help

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a 64 bit operating system to use more than 3.47GB Ram.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you used the tag 64 bit I am going to assume you are running 64 bit.

You will want to check and make sure that your Motherboard is compatible with that amount of ram. Some only offer an upper limit of 4GB.

You could have a faulty RAM stick. Simple way to check this is to use each stick and boot the machine. If they both read what they are suppose to then the issue is likely the above one or the below one.

Also as mentioned above 32 bit machines cannot run more than 4 GB.

Comment: to be fair, it was added on by @MichaelK

Comment: @Sathya the confusion!