# RAM is showing 2.99 GB instead of 3.25 GB in Windows XP Professional 32-bit

Tags: windows-xp, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5GB of my 4GB+ of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5gb-of-my-4gb-of-ram)

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E6550 with 4 GB of RAM. At that time, the system properties was showing RAM info as 3.25 GB on Windows XP Professional 32-bit.

Today, I upgraded the RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB. Now, I see that the system properties is reporting a decrease from 3.25 GB to 2.99 GB.

I'm aware that Windows 32-bit can only display up to 4 GB of RAM but why is it now only showing 2.99 GB?

My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce 7500 LE (512 MB) but I had the same card prior to the memory upgrade, and it was still showing 3.25 GB.

Can anyone tell me why it now shows 3.25 GB, especially after the upgrade?

Comment: Why did you put 8 GB of RAM into a machine running 32-bit Windows XP, anyway?

Comment: Hope Mike visits the question at SU.

Comment: I realize you aren't asking the usual question here (I don't know the answer), but I'm linking Jeff Atwood's blog post on the more-general problem anyway: [Dude, Where's My 4 Gigabytes of RAM?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram.html)

Comment: Dang... I just wasted my time with my detail answer.

Comment: You see this question almost everyday unfortunately.  Even though x64 Windows Vista/7 is the **exact** same price as x86 Vista/7,

Comment: In case anyone wants the actual answer, it's this: Your BIOS switched from optimizing the memory layout for a 32-bit OS to optimizing the memory layout for a 64-bit OS. If you have 4GB or less, it assumes 32-bit and maps as much memory as possible below 4GB. If you have more than 4GB, the BIOS assumes a 64-bit OS and freely re-maps memory above the 4GB mark. (Some BIOSes let you override the default. Look for an option called 'memory remapping'.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, Windows XP (32bit) only supports 4 gigs. That doesn't just apply to Windows XP. Instead, it applies to all 32bit OS. You will never see over 4 gigs if you are using a 32-bit Windows XP. However, I did find a more detail reason why your system shows less available ram than what is actually installed.

The 3GB-not-4GB RAM problem - Microsoft MSDN Blog **(*[Source](http://bit.ly/p9CvHf)*)**

> Due to an architectural decision made long ago, if you have 4GB of physical RAM installed, Windows is only able to report a portion of the physical 4GB of RAM (ranges from ~2.75GB to 3.5GB depending on the devices installed, motherboard's chipset & BIOS).
>
> This behavior is due to "memory mapped IO reservations". Those reservations overlay the physical address space and mask out those physical addresses so that they cannot be used for working memory. This is independent of the OS running on the machine.
>
> Significant chunks of address space below 4GB (the highest address accessible via 32-bit) get reserved for use by system hardware:
>
> - BIOS – including ACPI and legacy video support
> - PCI bus including bridges etc.
> - PCI Express support will reserve at least 256MB, up to 768MB depending on graphics card installed memory
>
> What this means is a typical system may see between ~256MB and 1GB of address space below 4GB reserved for hardware use that the OS cannot access. Intel chipset specs are pretty good at explaining what address ranges gets reserved by default and in some cases call out that 1.5GB is always reserved and thus inaccessible to Windows.

There is more information if you check out the source. However, you may be able to take advantage of the full 8 gigs installed if you followed these [instructions](http://bit.ly/pAEk1k).

*Speaking from personal experience, this is no new problem. I ran in to this same problem a few years ago when I built a 4-gig 32-bit Windows Vista system when Vista was first released. There were countless forum posts online related to this same topic.*

Comment: This answer is factually wrong. PAE allows to use up to 64 GiB on a 32bit system without problem. The limitation can be due, in part, to the BIOS and its limitations and to the (intentional) crippling of the XP kernel that doesn't allow to make use of PAE features even when available hardware-side.