# Only 2.99 Gb RAM usable out of 8GB in Windows 8 32 bit

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [8gb ram in 32bit operating system](https://superuser.com/questions/439124/8gb-ram-in-32bit-operating-system)

I have installed 8 GB RAM in my system. Also upgraded OS to Windows 8 32 bit.
My System configuration:

> Intel i7 960.
>   Ram Crossair 4 GB X 2 1666Mhz
>   Motherboard Asus Rampage III Gene
>   Video card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 240.
>   2 TB Seagate

**I have updated all drivers BIOS also. But my system showing only 2.99 GB out of 8GB usable RAM.**

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: 32 bit can't recognize all that RAM.

Comment: 32 bit OSes can absolutely use more than 4GB of RAM (32-bit Win2k3 datacenter could use 64 GB); Microsoft has chosen to not do enable/provide this in most of their 32-bit OSes however, so that is the limitation you are hitting.

Comment: wait for a PAE patch. Ask wj32: http://wj32.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/pae-patch-updated-for-windows-7-sp1/

Answer (score 8):

A 32 bit OS will not use more than 4 gb of ram inspite of adding more. This is due to many hardware architecture limitation

2^32 = 4294967296 bytes = 4194304 kb = 4096 mb = 4 gb

Install a 64 bit OS to use all of your RAM.

For viewing (not using) more than 4 gb of ram PAE (Physical address extension) must be enabled.

However there exist certain hacks such as [this](http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/32-bit-ram-barrier.html?lang=EN) one which which make use of all available ram however this heavily modifies your kernel, and your system might become unstable.

Note: this hack is only for Windows 7 32 bit

Until you can upgrade to a 64 bit OS you can use this [software](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/ramdisk.php) to make use of the additional unused ram as a high speed disk drive (cache)

A similar freeware version of the above software exist with limitation of only be able to support disks of size upto 4 GB. Check it [here](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk), check [this](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-search.php?search_term=RAM%20disk&x=0&y=0) too, or Google for more alternatives, if you are interested

Comment: I think by "a 32-bit OS" you mean "a 32-bit application"? Because obviously OSes that support PAE recognize the extra RAM.

Comment: @Mehrdad OSes that support PAE do recognize that extra RAM but due to a lock on the kernel imposed by Microsoft they are not allowed to use it.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. This seems like a pretty good answer.

Comment: +1 here too. @Algorithms: Sure, but that's just a Windows limitation imposed by Microsoft (and patchable, as you noted), not a general 32-bit OS limitation.

Answer (score 1):

32bit windows is only capable of using 2gb or 3gb, depending on version, edition and configuration.  The appropriate thing to do is to install 64-bit windows 8 (your Windows 8 license should cover both).

If you can't use 64-bit windows for some reason, your only real choice is to use special software to use the ram above 3gb for a cache.  Your motherboard probably came with software to do this.

Comment: Well it won't be stuff included with your motherboard, guarantee you that

Comment: Can you please give me some some software's name for enable RAM cache?