# Incorrect RAM size detected on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

Tags: windows-7

I use windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. I have installed a 2GB and two 1GB RAM on my computer, all in all 4GB, but my computer tells me that I have only 3GB all in all. It's as if the computer is registering the two 1GB sticks as only 2x 500MB.

Why is my computer showing and reacting as if I have only 3 gb when I personally have installed 4GB of RAM?

Comment: Are you sure the sticks are of the size you say they are...Try checking in something like CPU-Z or GPU-Z

Comment: How much RAM does the BIOS report is installed?

Comment: Thanks @tumchaaditya for correcting the title and to Jawa for the spelling of my question. The RAM fits in the sticks therefore I am sure they are. I am not sure why the computer is showing only 500 MB when physically installed is 1GB in each stick. the amount of GB that the computer shows is not the available one but the installed one. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @techie007 I am not en expert in computers, but when i try and look in dxdiag then it shows the following informations. BIOS: Default System BIOS Memory: 3072MB RAM, Fil: 1658 MB used, 4455 MB available.

Comment: What is your motherboard model? There are some mobo's that are finicky when it comes to arrangement of memory modules in the slots. Are you sure only 500Mb is detected on both 1Gb sticks, or only 1 Gb ram stick is being detected and the other 1 is not?

Comment: I meant RAM capacity and not the physical size of the stick!

Comment: @tumchaaditya The RAMs are 1GB each as specified on them. here are the informations I get threw dxdiag. Processor AMD Sempron (tm) Processor 3200+, 1,8 HGz. Grafik Card. AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series, DAC-type: Internal DAC (400MHz) Memory (approximately) 2296MB. As I wrote before i have installed a 2GB RAM and two 1GB RAM, all in all 4GB but the computer only shows 3072MB RAM available. According mother board specifications, it is possible to install 16GB RAM on this model. My operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit on my computer.

Comment: Could you try removing the 1x2Gb and seeing what you got then. If you get 2Gb do the same with the 1x2Gb (removing the 2x1Gb) and seeing if you get 2Gb. Where did you get the sticks? What number is printed on them? Sometimes they get sold as bigger than they are. Another possibility is that they all need to be the same size or you put the 2x1Gb in the wrong slots. The slots should be marked by color or number and you need to see in the manual if they match.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, part of the memory may be allocated to internal graphics card.

- [“Hardware components often use some of your internal system memory (RAM) for themselves. [...]”](http://www.howtogeek.com/131632/hardware-upgrade-why-windows-cant-see-all-your-ram/)

Another solution is to enable Memory Reamp.

- [“I have recently bought a dell studio 1555 with 4gb ram. But the total usable ram is only 2.96 gb and the ramaining is reserved [...]”](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-197079-total-installed-ram-not-usable)
- [Another example.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ebb61437-163e-4b63-84bf-986c9fe3475a/64-bit-windows-7-not-recognizing-4-gb-of-ram?forum=w7itproperf)

Or maybe you have mistakenly installed x86 instead of x64.

- [“I recently upgraded my computer's RAM to 4 GB. My 32-bit Windows installation shows only 3574 MB of the memory. [...]”](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5-gb-of-my-more-than-4-gb-of-ram)
- [3 GB barrier article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier)