# 4GB of installed Ram-- XP says 3.23 GB

Tags: windows-xp, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP and RAM 3.5GB+](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb)

I have a Dell desktop that had 2GB of Ram in it, but XP's control panel -> system setting said only 1.75 GB.  (This is 32 bit XP.)

I then installed another 2 GB, and now XP says I'm at 3.23 GB.  I'm sure my graphics card is using shared memory and that might explain some of it, but where can I check that setting to make sure?

Comment: duplicate? triplicate? probably more :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a setting you can change, really.  Your BIOS, video card, and other hardware need to map their own memory onto the system's address space.

See [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000811.html) for a simple explanation of what's happening.

You can run the System Information utility to verify that the computer sees the physical RAM; the metric you're interested in is "Total Physical Memory".

Comment: Thank you.  According to the utility I have 4GB of physical RAM, which is what I wanted to check-- that I seated both chips correctly.  My intel integrated graphics is using 384 MB according to the utility, so that leaves 500MB unaccounted for; most likely divvied up among various drivers and whatnot.

Comment: i'm afraid you calculation is wrong, 3.25 GB is all what is available to Windows 32-bit (due to the limitations of the x86 hardware architecture), your Intel GMA, "various drivers and whatnot" will then take from this whatever it takes to handle your current applications (dynamically shared video memory).

Comment: Hi Molly-- so the GMA and other hardware also use the 3.25 GB along with me?  If so, what uses (or can use) the remaining 800 MB?  I hadn't heard of x86 only being able to address 3.25 GB-- I thought it could address the entire 4GB, or just about.

Answer (score 1):

These are some questions that popped up after you typed the title of your question, all of which contain information you are asking about.

- [4 GB of RAM installed but only 2.97 GB usable. What gives?](https://superuser.com/questions/50138/4-gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2-97gb-usable-what-gives-closed)
- [Why does Windows only show about 3.5 GB of my 4 GB of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb)
- [Where did the other .8 GB of RAM go?](https://superuser.com/questions/7964/where-did-the-other-8-gb-of-ram-go)
- https://superuser.com/questions/17827/using-3-gb-ram-in-vista-windows732-bit
- [Why is usable RAM less than total RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/54056/why-is-usable-ram-less-than-total-ram)
- [How to Check RAM Size without Looking at Motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/27006/how-to-check-ram-size-without-looking-at-motherboard)

Answer (score 0):

32-bit Windows XP can only address up to a maximum of ~3.5 GB of RAM. The other 256MB or so is probably shared with your integrated graphics card.

You need a 64-bit operating system to use 4GB or more of RAM. Windows XP 64-bit is not recommended because few companies have drivers that support 64-bit Windows XP. Most start at Windows Vista 64 at least.

Comment: this is only valid if the video memory is fixed in the BIOS and not dynamically shared (which is standard today).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening: Windows takes up some of your RAM, and that is not Included. Furthermore, You can't actually use all 4 GB with 32 bit Windows XP, because it only supports 3.5 GB of memory. You could buy Windows XP 64 bit, but I do not recommend it- it has compatibility issues. Your best bet is to relax and deal with it. You will find that most computers have this "problem".