# Installed RAM : 4 GB but 2.96GB Usable......why?

Tags: windows-7, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [4 GB of Ram installed but only 2.97GB usable. What gives?](https://superuser.com/questions/50138/4-gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2-97gb-usable-what-gives)

Installed RAM : 4 GB but 2.96GB Usable......why?

I installed 2 x 2 GB DDR2 800 MHz.

My Windows is Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

**Is my ram Faulty?**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/67444/is-there-way-to-enable-4gb-ram-in-32-bit-windows-os

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/50138
 http://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb
 http://superuser.com/questions/7964/where-did-the-other-8-gb-of-ram-go
 http://superuser.com/questions/17827/using-3-gb-ram-in-vista-windows732-bit
 http://superuser.com/questions/54056/why-is-usable-ram-less-than-total-ram
 http://superuser.com/questions/27006/how-to-check-ram-size-without-looking-at-motherboard

@OP: Please search before posting.Or atleast look at related questions when you enter the Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are running a 32 bit OS. You would have known that if you had used the search box.

Comment: but i thought windows 7 32 bit will support 4 gb ram

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought that... It is posted everywhere that it won't. You need the 64bit version.

Comment: do you mean then  1) 2gb module and 1) 1 gb module of RAM was enough on Windows 7 32 Bit/ Windows XP 32 bit. no use of extra 1 GB available RAM

Comment: Windows 7 32 bit: Supports <=3GB. Windows 7 64bit: Supports more than 3GB

Comment: Turning memory remapping *off* in your BIOS, if it has such an option, may get you an extra .2GB to .5GB. But you'll never get more than 3.5GB on 32-bit Windows 7.