# About RAM. I am unable to check my original size of RAM

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP and RAM 3.5GB+](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb)

RAM was 2 GB and extended to 2 GB but it's showing only 2.96 GB. And I checked all the way but could not find the Solution. I am using Windows 7 32-Bit OS.

Answer (score 4):

Most 32-bit operating systems can only access around 3 GB of RAM. There are many duplicates of this question:

- [Where did the other .8 GB of RAM go?](https://superuser.com/questions/7964/where-did-the-other-8-gb-of-ram-go)
- [4 GB of RAM installed but only 2.97 GB usable. What gives?](https://superuser.com/questions/50138/4-gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2-97gb-usable-what-gives)
- [Installed RAM : 4 GB but 2.96GB Usable......why?](https://superuser.com/questions/141930/installed-ram-4-gb-but-2-96gb-usable-why)

Comment: if a question is likely a duplicate of other questions, please post the links in comments, not answers.  thanks.

Comment: @quack quixote Ok, thanks for letting me know. Is there a page that discusses etiquette for that sort of thing?

Comment: yes; it'll be on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ somewhere.  Meta is the place to discuss usage of Super User, Stack Overflow and Server Fault.  start with the [main FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) and search around; if you can't find something, post a new question there and the Meta community will answer and/or direct you to an earlier post.

Comment: @quack quixote Ok, thanks. I've actually looked around quite a bit there, but haven't found a FAQ that covers the stuff like this that I don't know that I don't know (i.e. it never occurred to me to ask "if the question I'm answering is a duplicate, should I post my answer in the comments instead of the answer field?"). I've seen it done both ways on all the sites. Anyway, now I know, so thanks again.

Comment: in this case, the first sentence of your post is actually an answer to the question, so it's fine as an answer post.  it's the rest that should be posted as a comment.  (there are lots of cases where a question is migrated here from SO/SF, and half the answers include "this belongs on SU" or similar... yuck.)  don't sweat it, this is just part of learning to use the site.